# Visual Studio Xamarin Inherited Class Object Initialization no Intellisense

Tags: c#, xamarin, intellisense

When I create a new class that inherits from any UIControl, I am not seeing intellisense when trying to initialize a new object. Specifically, this only happens when doing anonymous initialization. For the purposes of demonstration, I'll use a UIView. Does anyone know the reason for this, if there is a workaround, or if I am doing something wrong?

```
public class Foo : UIView
{
    public int bar { get; set; }
    public Foo() { }
}

public class Test
{
    public Test() {
        //no intellisense when hitting spacebar between braces
        var myFoo = new Foo { };
        //can still set properties however
        var myFoo2 = new Foo { bar = 1 };
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2013 with Xamarin 3.029.

Comment: @SteveMitcham it compiles without adding an access modifier. Adding public does not solve the problem. Thank you though.

Comment: Sorry,  quick glances get you in trouble sometimes.

Comment: Thank you. I edited to include public so it doesn't cause any confusion.

Comment: Have you asked over in the xamarin forums?

Comment: I noticed you _can_ force it to appear with ctrl+space, so I wonder if it's a Visual Studio thing trying to save you from the (rather large) list that comes along with inheriting from UIView.  I tried inheriting from `UIKit.UIVibrancyEffect` and intellisense worked, so it's not just a UIKit thing.  I also looked in VS Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense but found nothing of interest.  I'm really curious what exactly is going on here too.

Comment: Do you have a plugin like resharper loaded that affects intellisense?

Comment: There are no plugins installed